# How to correctly parse a sequence of arbitrary bytes

Tags: parsing, rust, utf-8, byte

**Edit: changed title and question to make them more general and easier to find when looking for this specific issue**

I'm parsing a sequence of arbitrary bytes (`u8`) from a file, and I've come to a point where I had to use `std::str::from_utf8_unchecked` (which is `unsafe`) instead of the usual `std::str::from_utf8`, because it seemingly was the only way to make the program work.

```
fn parse(seq: &[u8]) {
    . . .
    let data: Vec<u8> = unsafe {
        str::from_utf8_unchecked(&value[8..data_end_index])
            .as_bytes()
            .to_vec()
    };
    . . .
}
```

This, however, is probably leading to some inconsistencies with the actual use of the program, because with non trivial use I get an `io::Error::InvalidData` with the message *"stream did not contain valid UTF-8"*.

Comment: You should never use `from_utf8_unchecked` with user-supplied data. If `from_utf8` fails it is because you are not passing valid UTF-8 (nor ASCII) text, the sane thing in that case would probably be to check for that particular error and ignore that chunk, or something similar.

Comment: @rodrigo I understand, so it means that my parsing algorithm is probably not correct. It's strange because in earlier tests it was ok but with a more complex one it wouldn't work and it already gave an issue related to UTF-8, which was swept under the carpet by using `std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`.

Comment: Which is why you should never use `from_utf8_unchecked()` in this case: instead of a failing test, you got UB.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was caused by the fact that I was converting the sequence of arbitrary bytes into a string which, in Rust, must contain only valid UTF-8 characters. The conversion was done because I thought I could call `to_vec` only after `as_bytes`, without realizing that a `&[u8]` is in fact a slice of bytes already.

I was converting the byte slice into a vec, but only after performing a useless and harmful conversion into a string, which doesn't make sense because not all bytes are valid ASCII characters that can be parsed as UTF-8 characters to create a Rust string.

The correct code is the following:

```
let data: Vec<u8> = value[8..data_end_index].to_vec();
```